# Google Material Layout Grid overwriting itself?

Tags: grid, material-ui

I'm trying to implement Material's layout grid for web. When I put in a span size for columns, the width (in this case 33.33%) is being overwritten by the same class with `width: auto;`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had mdc-layout-grid--inner instead of mdc-layout-grid__inner